# How can I concat column using FluentPDO?

Tags: php, mysql, fluent

Lets say I've table `user` with columns `firstname`, `lastname` and `col3`

```
SELECT col3, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as firstlast 
FROM users
```

This query will work fine in MySql but how can I replicate this in FluentPDO?

I can't find it on official documentation [Fluent Documentation](http://fluentpdo.com/documentation.html) and If it is not present in FluentPDO then what can be work around for this?

Any suggestion/hint would be helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with FluentPDO but from the documentation link you send, this should work:

```
$query = $fpdo->from("users")->select("CONCAT(users.firstname, ' ', users.lastname) as firstlast");
```

Comment: Thanks :) How can i miss this -_-